# SyntaxError: Unexpected token B, can't debug all errors are minified/angular.min

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, gulp, minify

I'm getting this error, and don't know how to debug or where to start to solve this.. I've tried console logging everything but only the error shows(in server file and in frontend js scripts). I have no error in my term when I run my gulp server either..

```
angular.min.js:92 SyntaxError: Unexpected token B
 at Object.parse (native)
 at Object.ac [as fromJson] (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:23:360)
 at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:229:494)
 at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:44:36)
 at http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:45:288
 at c (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:43:305)
 at d (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:44:6)
 at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:44:165)
 at $get (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:76:421)
 at compile (http://localhost:8000/bundle.js:8:23333) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:92$get @ angular.min.js:68J @ angular.min.js:54g @ angular.min.js:47(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:46k @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7$get.h.$broadcast @ angular.min.js:115y.transitionTo.y.transition.M.then.y.transition.y.transition @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7l.promise.then.J @ angular.min.js:101(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:102$get.h.$eval @ angular.min.js:113$get.h.$digest @ angular.min.js:110$get.h.$apply @ angular.min.js:113(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:18d @ angular.min.js:35c @ angular.min.js:18dc @ angular.min.js:18Wc @ angular.min.js:17(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:216a @ angular.min.js:146(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:31r @ angular.min.js:7c @ angular.min.js:31
```

has anyone run into a similar error/ know where I could start to fix this? (server/frontend?)

Comment: Hello. This kind of error generally occurs when trying to parse a JSON-invalid string with `JSON.parse`. Are you using `angular.fromJson` somewhere in your code?

Comment: why don't you just try to use the non minified version of angular to get a more detailed error?

Comment: no not using angular.fromJson anywhere, I even commented out all lines that I'm parsing JSON and still getting the error, I traced it down to a express middleware that if I comment out, it stops passing the error. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seemed, all it was, was a polluted localStorage.. I cleared it and everything is fine again.... sigh. Thanks for the answers though everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Remove min from your script declaration and run the code again. Open the console and the error should be right there in human readable format.

Its probably something really basic even something miss-spelled. You can add min again after to keep everything quick.